Including ] symbol in negated scanset in scanf function in C
I want to go over input that consists of chars some of which are parentheses and brackets of all kinds and check whether all parentheses are opened and closed correctly (standard rules). I wanted to use scanf("%*[^[{(<>)}]\n]) to read all non-bracket characterd without storing them.
However ] symbol is always seen as the end of the set.
I tried searching for ways to deal with it, some say to put it in the end  -
scanf("%*[^[{(<>)}\n]])
Some say to put it right after ^ -
scanf("%*[^][{(<>)}\n])
I even tried the escaping:
scanf("%*[^[{(<>)}\]\n])
Nothing worked so far.
Anyone knows how to include it?
Thanks in advance

If you want to parse such complex input, then perhaps use regular expressions instead?

Using "%[^]...]" works as expected for me: https://ideone.com/b9wYzA

On a different note, please don't use trailing space in your format string. See e.g. What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string? for details.

@Someprogrammerdude
It's a basic task for my course, so ve have a very limited set of tools allowed for it. Also I've read that scanf doen't exactly support regex.

You need to check the return value from scanf()! .... if (scanf("%*[^][{(<>)}\n]%s", &c) == 1) printf("%c", c); else fprintf(stderr, "scanf error\n");. BTW: you cannot write a string (the "%s" specifier) into a single character (the &c argument)

@pmg
I tried it again, literally copy-pasted your line and it works as immediately closed format bracket (ignore all symbols, no exceptions), discards the whole input. Could it depend on OS, IDE, compiler?

No, it does not depend on OS, IDE, compiler. At most it depends on how you deal with scanf failures. You need to check the return value from scanf()!

@pmg
Corrected %s to %c. Checked the return,  int k = scanf("%*[^][{(<>)}\n]%c", &c);
k equals 0 (no inputs assigned to variables)

Can you do int k = sscanf("your (input) with [embedded] whitespace <and> everything", "%*[^][{(<>)}\n]%c", &c); (notice extra s) and show that?

@pmg
Okay, I tried and found it works in a weird way. Both your first and last suggestion work as intended as long as ] is not the first char in the input (which was the case in my test).  If it's in the middle then k=1 and c=first bracket of input. If ] is the first character then k=0 and no value is assigned to char c.

When ] is the first character in input, scanf immediately fails because ] is in the "excluded" scanset. That's why I added - in my ideone example

@pmg
I see, thank you very much

@user3121023
Also works. I expected scanf("%*[^][{(<>)}\n]%c") to work the same way as scanf("%*[^][{(<>)}\n]"); then scanf("%c",&c);, to skip untill it meets a bracket, and then read next char to c, but it doesn't.

The only “zero or more matches” in the scanf() family is white space (and %n).  All other conversions match one or more characters.
